# Consecutive indices of a Python list in for loop, without specifying indices

Tags: python, list, iterator

I can loop through a Python (v.2.6) list without specifying indices, using the following "[Pythonic](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-pythonic)" syntax:

```
the_list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
for item in the_list:
    print item + 2
```

But if I want to perform an operation on two consecutive indices, I think I then have to specify index numbers, with a corresponding change to the range of the `for` loop:

```
the_list = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]
for i in xrange(len(the_list)-1):
    print the_list[i] + the_list[i+1]
```

Is that correct? Or is there a way to remain Pythonic and avoid using the expression `xrange(len(the_list)-1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fond of the [`pairwise`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe as listed in the docs to the `itertools` module:

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Then...

```
for x, x_next in pairwise(the_list):
    ...
```

You can also just `zip` the list with a slice of itself:

```
for x, x_next in zip(the_list, the_list[1:]):
    ...
```

Comment: And alternatively there is `enumerate()` giving not only items but also the indexes.

Comment: @senderle: Thanks, those are very helpful. `zip()` looks like lower overhead for one-time use.

Comment: @nightcracker: With `enumerate()`, it seems I am generating `j` without needing to use it. Since I must use `the_list[i+1]`, there's not much gained by writing `j` for `the_list[i]`, is there?

Comment: Can anyone show how `enumerate()` could be used for this - I must be temporarily dense, I can't see how (w/o using some ugly code to avoid `index out of bounds` condition)

Comment: @Levon, I was going to say the same thing as nightcracker, with the caveat that I think you might as well just zip a slice in that case, since you're creating a copy either way. (But note that `enumerate` takes a `start` keyword arg: `for i, x in enumerate(the_list[:-1], start=1): print x + the_list[i]`)

Comment: @senderle I've learned about `zip` reading SO, and I knew about the starting parameter for `enumerate` - what I *didn't* think about was adjusting the size of the list via a the slicing operation. Thanks.